# Changing CPU speed and dynamic VHD to static VHD in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, vhd

I have two question. First, Can someone help me with advice about how to limit and improve the CPU usage on the VMs (hyper-v)? Or maybe you have links about this topic. The other question is about how can I change dynamic VHDs to static VHDs?

Comment: It seems from your question that you might be hoping that changing to fixed VHDs will meaninfully lower your CPU usage.  I doubt that's the case.  Go ahead and measure it, though.

Comment: You might want to concentrate on simply learning the basic capabilities of Hyper-V before you worry about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

On converting VHDS:

Click the Edit Disk action within Hyper-V Manager then select the dynamic VHD. On the Action screen, select the Convert option to make the dynamic VHD a fixed VHD. You should  be prompted for a name for the fixed VHD.  You'll need space as it copies the contents to a new disk.

For a beginning on best practices take a look at the [ebook available here](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/virtualization.aspx). as well as the [infrastructure planning guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897507.aspx)

Limiting CPU usage. [See this article](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/general/controlling-processor-resources-hyper-v-guests.html) for details.  In a nutshell you set limits under the processor tab.

Answer (score 0):

if this is r2 then download the newest best practice analyser from MS.